# Returning String value from the Mockito when()

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to specific String value in mockito using when() method like

```
@Mock Individual indProvider;
when(indProvider.asProvider().getProviderId()).thenReturn("795316051750");
```

But I am getting exception

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
0 matchers expected, 1 recorded.
This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
//incorrect:
someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
//correct:
someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.
```

How can I return specific String in such case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's probably somewhere in the code a mockito Matcher used outside of stubbed invocation or verified invocation.

If your code base use JUnit I recommend the use of the mockito runner, it will validate the mockito use for each test method, which means any issue can be pinpointed to the test incorrectly written.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TheTest {
    @Test public void shoudl_perform_something() { ... }
}
```

Or with a mockito rule (since 1.10.17)

```
public class TheTest {
    @Rule MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();
    @Test public void should_perform_something() { ... }
}
```

You don't have to use have `@Mock`s in your test to benefit from this framework validation.
And anyway both are the *preferred* ways to instantiate mocks compared to `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(...)`

Also which version of mockito are you using ? I believe Mockito has improved some messages with the location of the bad code.

---

Note that this code cannot work properly, because `indProvider.asProvider()` is not stubbed so mockito will use the default value which is `null`. You have to do this either way (deep stubs is here for legacy code, a mock returning a mock is usually considered a code smell and it shows the tested code breaks the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)) :

```
@Mock(answer = RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS) Individual indProvider;
// ...
when(indProvider.asProvider().getProviderId()).thenReturn("795316051750");
```

or as answered by @przemek, it's more verbose and shows the same weakness in the tested code.

```
@Mock(answer = RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS) Individual indProvider;
@Mock Provider provider;
// ...
when(indProvider.asProvider()).thenReturn(provider);
when(provider.getProviderId()).thenReturn("795316051750");
```

---

I advise you to read this book ([Growing Object Oriented Software Guided by Tests](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503627)), it's one of the very best book you can read about writing softwares guided by tests. I find it even more important than infamous Effective Java book.

Answer (score 1):

You should use multiple `when()` interceptions:

```
@Mock Individual indProvider;
@Mock Provider provider;

when(indProvider.asProvider()).thenReturn(provider);
when(provider.getProviderId()).thenReturn("795316051750");
```

Comment: This answer looks pretty reasonable to me. I wonder if the error is reported for some other test code which is mixing matchers and raw values--often the error message can be helpful and it does provide some detail here which doesn't seem to apply to your question. Personally, I prefer JMockit to Mockito.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it like this:

```
Mockito.when(indProvider.asProvider().getProviderId())
  .thenAnswer(t -> "795316051750");
```